# Lectura de Ficheros en Java usando una ruta de MacOS

Tags: java, archivo, macos

En clase estamos dando la lectura de ficheros.txt en Java usando el editor de código Netbeans, el caso es que extraigo la ruta del fichero a ejecutar (uso MacOS) y la copio donde debería ir la ruta normal de Windows.Cuando ejecuto el programa no se imprime el texto del fichero, si no que se imprime la ruta como si fuera un String cualquiera.¿Alguien tiene idea de qué  puede estar pasando?

Este es el código:

```
File fichero = new File("/Users/lauracasoalonso/Desktop/lecturaficheros/LecturaFicheros");
```

Y este es el resultado en consola:

> Mensaje: /Users/lauracasoalonso/Desktop/lecturaficheros/LecturaFicheros (No such file or directory)

Comment: parece que te falta agregar la extensión del archivo

Comment: Ya escribí el .txt al final del archivo en el código y nada, sigue dando el mismo resultado

Comment: en tu pregunta indicas que quieres leer **ficheros.txt** pero en la ruta no estás apuntando a ese archivo, el mensaje es claro, Java no pudo encontrar el archivo, verifica la ruta completa a tu archivo